# Document Management System Editor

Tags: jquery, ms-word, tinymce, ckeditor, dms

I am building a web version (mostly jquery html5 with asp.net in the background) of an existing document management system. Existing software is built on .NET Win Forms and uses Microsoft Word as an editing control.

Since I am building a web version, I want to stay away from Microsoft Word and have been considering Ckeditor and TinyMce as document editing control alternatives. However these controls lack the paging, header/footer and print perfect WYSIWYG functionaltiy of Microsoft Word. So

1. Is there anyway to extend Ckeditor, TinyMce or any similar control to have Word like features ?
2. Is there any existing (it can be commercial) control with Word or Google Docs like features that can be used on the web ?
3. Since this will be an intranet application and all my clients have Microsoft Word installed on their computers, is there anyway to use Microsoft Word as an activex control and somehow integrate it with jquery or asp.net ?

Edit: Just to be complete I have found several alternatives but I am still open to suggestions.

1. CKEditor, TinyMCE like HTML Editors (these lack paging, header/footer features)
2. Use Microsoft Word in Internet Explorer as ActiveX control (platform and browser dependent. Requires users to have Office Installed). **I still need some pointers how to accomplish this.**
3. Use Word Web App with Sharepoint 2010. This is an expensive alternative and not sure completely feasible. (cant edit in reading view)
4. Use Silverlight or flash components like Telerik RichTextBox (seems like the best alternative but wont work on iPad, iPhone etc.)
5. Dont allow editing inside the web page. Whenever editing is required launch Word on client computer and have it save it to server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The problem is how to create such features in HTML. I haven't seen anything beside Google Docs that uses a very complex editor to provide its features skipping the problems in the browsers or HTML.
2. Not that I know, but I haven't searched for them.
3. Yes, as long as you're happy using IE then you should be able to use word as an activeX control IIRC.

Comment: It seems like word web app comes close to google docs. not very close but close. there are also silverlight components in the market for this purpose.